# Merging JSON objects in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server

We have a base table which has custom column_values column
`Table_Structure`:

```
User_Dimension-
Userid,username,addresss,Custom_value
```

`Userid` is the primary key and customer can map the fields present in the file using our UI.

If any of the columns present in the files doesn't fit in the column present in our base tables, we will create a custom column and store it in the form of json.

```
Userid,username,addresss,Custom_value
234,AK4140,BANGLORE,{"Pin:"522413","State":"Maharastra"}
```

The data will be stored as mentioned in the above in a staging table

Note: for the table `User_Dimension` there can be data from multiple files so my custom values are different for each file and that information is stored in a meta data table.

We are using SCD Type 1 for dimension tables

The problem is to merge JSON column.

Consider this scenario:

```
User_Dimension 

Userid,username,addresss,Service_Type,User_Type,Custom_value
234,ak4140,banglore,null,null,{"Pin:"522413","State":"Maharastra"}
```

The above entry was present in my `user_dimension` from File1

Now I need to push below value to my table from File2

```
Userid,username,addresss,Service_Type,User_Type,Custom_value
234,NULL,NULL,Customer,DVV,{"Birthdate:"19-09-1995","State":"Karnataka"}
```

I am merging both the values based on the `Userid`.

The problem is `Custom_Value` column. From the above entries I need to update this column as shown here:

```
Userid,username,addresss,Service_Type,User_Type,Custom_value
234,ak4140,banglore,Customer,DVV,{"Pin:"522413","State":"Karnataka","Birthdate":"19-09-1995"}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems you haven't taken the orientation [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) yet. You may also wish to read through [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) to see if you could restructure your question so that it's answerable. For example, what is processing the staging table(s) to migrate the data to your dimension table(s)? If it's T-SQL stored procedure code what functions and techniques have you attempted to use?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function which can *perhaps* be used to merge two json files:

```sql
create or alter function dbo.FN_JSON_MERGE(@pJson1 NVARCHAR(MAX), @pJson2 NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Get keys...
    declare @t table ([key] nvarchar(max) collate database_default, [value] nvarchar(max) collate database_default, row_id int identity)

    insert into @t
    select [key], [value]
    from OPENJSON(@pJson1)

    -- Merge values from @pjson2
    update t
    set value = oj.value
    from @t t
    inner join OPENJSON(@pJson2) oj
        ON  oj.[key]  collate database_default = t.[key]  collate database_default

    insert into @t
    select [key], [value]
    from    OPENJSON(@pJson2) o
    where not exists(
        select 1
        from @t t2
        where t2.[key]  collate database_default = o.[key]  collate database_default
    )
    -- Finally generate new json...
    set @pJson2 = ''
    select  @pJson2 = @pJson2 + ',' + '"' + [key] + '": "' + (value) + '"'
    from @t 
    order by [row_id]
    
    return '{' + stuff(@pJson2, 1, 1, '') + '}'

    
END
```

Test code:

```sql
select dbo.FN_JSON_MERGE('{"Pin":"522413","State":"Maharastra"}'
, '{"Birthdate":"19-09-1995","State":"Karnataka"}')
-- returns {"Pin": "522413","State": "Karnataka","Birthdate": "19-09-1995"}
```

But there are lot of BUTs. It might not handle very long strings / strings with quotes or other more weird jsons etc.
Also, it doesn't always keep the same attribute order as original json.
It's likely to be *very* slow.
Finally, it doesn't handle if you want to merge data from 3 files.
Right now, the second argument values always overwrite first.

But maybe it can be of some use. You can always create a procedure which does this for better performance.